# solution of the equation $2\sin\theta/2=\cos(\theta(n-1/2))?$

Tags: trigonometry

What is the general solution of the equation  $$2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=\cos\left(\theta(n-\frac{1}{2})\right)?$$
Is it possible to analytically find all the solutions in the interval $(0, \pi)$?

Comment: Your notation needs clarification.

Comment: Do you mean $2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}=\cos\left(\theta\left(n-\frac12\right)\right)$?

Comment: Hopefully my edit is correct

Comment: @G_o_pi_i_e What progress have you made so far? Please indicate exactly where you are stuck. This help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It also shows that you are interested in the question and don't just want people to do  your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Comment: I am actually interested to find the solution of the equation $$1-4\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{\sin\theta(n-1)}{\sin\theta n}, ~~\text{ for }\theta\in(0, \pi).$$ I have simplified the problem to the equation written above and stuck.

Comment: Not sure how to do it but wolfram says its doable - http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+1-4sin%5E2(t%2F2)%3Dsin(t(n-1))%2Fsin(t×n)+for+t

Comment: Are you trying to solve for $\theta$ or for n?

Comment: @browngreen : Solving for $\theta$ only.

Comment: you need to tell what is $n$

Comment: Here $n$ is any natural number.